# How can I call a method on an object that is stored in a polymorphic array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

Hi and thanks for taking time to look at my problem.

I am trying to call a method on an object held in an object array.

There are three classes: Cards, Guard and Deck.

The Guard class extends the Cards class.

The array is of type 'Cards' and is instantiated in the Deck class.

The Cards class is pretty much empty:

```
public class Cards  {
}
```

The object being stored in the array is of type Guard. Here is the Guard class and it's state and methods:

```
public class Guard extends Cards{

    private int cardScore = 2;
    private String cardName = "Guard";
    private String cardAbility = "this is the guard's ability";

    public void printGuardInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("This card score fo the guard is:      "+cardScore);
        System.out.println("The card name is: "+ cardName);
        System.out.println("The card ability is" + cardAbility);
    }
}
```

I am instantiating the array in the Deck class. I am then filling a array of type Cards with objects of type Guard.This is polymorphism, I believe.

This works and I can print the reference variables held at each index point.

```
public class Deck {
    Cards[] deck = new Cards[16];

    public Cards[] getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }

    public void addGuards()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            deck[i] = new Guard();
            deck[i].printGuardInfo();// Error: cannot resolve method     printGuardInfo()
        }
    }  
}
```

My problem is that I now cannot call the printGuardInfo() method on deck[i].

I have searched and googled for a while now but with no success. I feel like I need an interface, or abstract class of some sort. Unfortunately I am not knowledgeable enough in these areas.

Any help at all is much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried casting it properly (deck[i]).printGuardInfo();, Doh! just realised that is not quite right try ((Guard)deck[i]).printGuardInfo();

Comment: do you know about `instanceof` and `casting`?

Comment: Your code will be clearer if you use `Card` instead of `Cards`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I´d promote something like this:

Make `Cards` an `interface`

```
public interface Cards  {
    void print();
}
```

Make `Guard` implement this interface and override the `print` method there with the needed information.

```
public class Guard implements Cards{
    // ... Other methods and stuff
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("This card score fo the guard is:      "+cardScore);
        System.out.println("The card name is: "+ cardName);
        System.out.println("The card ability is" + cardAbility);
    }
    // ... Other methods and stuff
}
```

Now in the loop you just have to call

```
deck[i].print();
```

What is getting printed now will be depending on the actual implementation of what has to be printed, but in generall the class `Cards` will know that it can `print` now.

Edit: Following @chrylis comment, your class should be called `Card` instead of `Cards`. The reason here? It´s like a simple plan for a single type of `Card`(class here), but doesn´t represent multiple `Cards`(multiple cards would be instances of `Card`).

Comment: With the additional note that the type name should really be `Card`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps me understand interfaces better and solves my problem.

Comment: Also, thank you Chrylis on the advice on naming, really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

While some of the proposed solutions make sense in the narrow case (using a combination of `instanceof` and casting the impacted `Cards` element to `Guard` in order to invoke `printGuardInfo`), there might be a broader problem with the design of your inheritance.

Assuming `Cards` is not really an empty class (otherwise the hierarchy does really not produce any benefit), my advice is to group your card objects under a common interface or abstract class (say, `Card`), and have that interface provide an abstraction for general methods such as `printInfo`, which is then implemented by each `Card` type (you'd get the `printGuardInfo` code inside the `Guard` implementation there).

In turn, when iterating your array, you'd invoke `printInfo` on each card, knowing that each and every child of `Card` has its own `printInfo` implementation, without the need to cast or use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the `Card` to a `Guard`:

```
((Guard) deck[i]).printGuardInfo();
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest, most object-oriented way to do this is to change `printGuardInfo` to `toString`:

```
public String toString()
{
    return new StringBuilder("This card score fo the guard is:      ")
                  .append(cardScore).append('\n')
                  .append("The card name is: ")
                  .append(cardName).append('\n')
                  .append("The card ability is ")
                  .append(cardAbility)
                  .toString();
}
```

You can then call `String guardInfo = deck[i].toString();` to get the guard info and write it to standard output, a logger, etc.

`public String toString()` is inherited from `Object`, so no casting is needed to call it.

Answer (score 2):

R2-D2 is right, but if you want to be more 'polymorphic' you should do something like This

```
public interface ICard {
    public void printInfo();

}

public class Card implements ICard{

  public void printInfo(
    System.out.println("Card Info");
  }
}

public class Guard extends Card {

   public void printInfo{
        System.out.println("GUARD Info");
 }
}


public vlass Deck{
...
public void addGuards()
{
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
          deck[i] = new Guard();
          deck[i].printInfo();
        }
    }  

}
```

Or even use an abstract class